# Multiple Div with a Button for each Div to Toggle Show/Hide the Div

Tags: jquery, html

I need some suggestions, Currently I have multiple Div to show more details of the item.

Eg.

```
<div id="item-1">Testestesttestetstests<a href="#" id="showmore1">Show More</a></div>
<div id="item-1-more" style="display:none">Contents Contents Contents</div>

<div id="item-2">Testestesttestetstests<a href="#" id="showmore2">Show More</a></div>
<div id="item-2-more" style="display:none">Contents Contents Contents</div>

<div id="item-3">Testestesttestetstests<a href="#" id="showmore3">Show More</a></div>
<div id="item-3-more" style="display:none">Contents Contents Contents</div>
```

and the Javascript

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#showmore1").click(function(){
            $("#item-1-more").slideToggle("fast");
        });
});
</script>
```

So my plan is to use the if else statement or just implement straight away to control when each button is clicked to show different contents from each Div. Eg.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#showmore1").click(function(){
        $("#item-1-more").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#showmore2").click(function(){
        $("#item-2-more").slideToggle("fast");
    });
    $("#showmore3").click(function(){
        $("#item-3-more").slideToggle("fast");
    });
});
</script>
```

I'm not sure if this is a good way to implement it or how do I do it in the other way and is more efficient?

And yes, each Div will have different contents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make this more generic by giving the HTML elements common classes instead of individual ids, and then having just one click handler bound to anchors of the specified class - within the handler, use DOM navigation/traversal methods to get to the associated content div:

```js
$("a.showmore").click(function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).parent().next().slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```css
.morehidden { display: none; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>Testestesttestetstests<a href="#" class="showmore">Show More</a></div>
<div class="morehidden">Contents Contents Contents</div>

<div>Testestesttestetstests<a href="#" class="showmore">Show More</a></div>
<div class="morehidden">Contents Contents Contents</div>

<div>Testestesttestetstests<a href="#" class="showmore">Show More</a></div>
<div class="morehidden">Contents Contents Contents</div>
```

So what I've done specifically is to remove all of the element IDs, they're not needed. I've added the `showmore` class to the links. And I've added a `morehidden` class to the contents divs that sets them to `display:none` by default (this is tidier than coding `style="display:none"` in each).

In the click handler, `this` will refer to the individual item that was clicked, so `$(this).parent()` gets the div that is the parent of the link, and then `.next()` gets the associated content div.

Comment: Okay I can get this to work if its in <div> form. What if the contents are in <tr><td> and im trying to toggle the next <tr> to show/hide ?

Comment: Then use whatever combination of `.closest()`, `.next()`, `.find()`, etc. that you need to navigate from one to the other. Read through [the list of jQuery tree traversal methods](http://api.jquery.com/category/traversing/tree-traversal/). If you have a link in a `<td>` and you want to show/hide the *following* `<tr>` then something like `$(this).closest("tr").next().toggle()` should do it.

Comment: I'm not psychic, I'd need to see your actual HTML - maybe you could add it to your question. But think about the general principle here: don't just try to copy code directly from my previous comment, see if you can figure out for yourself what the parent/child/sibling/etc. relationship is between your elements and then go from there.

Comment: Nvm! Sorry. I got it worked! It was because of I put the class at <td> instead of the <tr> for the toggle. Thanks! Good explanation as well! New to this code.

Answer (score 1):

A shorter code can be this

```
$('.show-more').on('click', function(){
    $(this).next().slideToggle('fast');
});
```

For this, you'll have to add CSS class `.show-more` to each Show more button/link.

Comment: Can you elaborate more? I'm average on HTML and CSS.

Comment: It adds a click event listener to all `.show-more` elements and toggles the element which is next to the instance of `.show-more` you clicked on.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution https://jsfiddle.net/tesfpw3z/

```js
$('a').click(function(e){
  e.preventDefault();
  $(this).closest('tr').next().find('td').slideToggle("fast");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td id="item-1">Testestesttestetstests<a href="#" id="showmore1">Show More</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="item-1-more" style="display:none">Contents Contents Contents</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="item-2">Testestesttestetstests<a href="#" id="showmore2">Show More</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="item-2-more" style="display:none">Contents Contents Contents</td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td id="item-3">Testestesttestetstests<a href="#" id="showmore3">Show More</a></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td id="item-3-more" style="display:none">Contents Contents Contents</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Hope this will help you.